# i am try to write code to detect beacons but i am getting error and not able to solve

Tags: android, flutter, dart, beacon

so I have 4 beacons and I wrote the code below to detect them

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_beacon/flutter_beacon.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  StreamSubscription<RangingResult>? _streamRanging;
  final _regionBeacons = <Region, List<Beacon>>{};
  final _beacons = <Beacon>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Request location permission
    requestPermission();
  }

  void requestPermission() async {
    if (await Permission.location.request().isGranted) {
      // Location permission granted
      initBeacon();
    } else {
      // Location permission denied
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Location Permission Required'),
          content: Text(
              'Please grant location permission to enable beacon scanning.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                // Open app settings to allow the user to grant permission manually
                openAppSettings();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  // FlutterBeacon.initialize();
  initBeacon() async {
    try {
      await flutterBeacon.initializeScanning;
      print('Beacon scanner initialized');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    // Configure the regions to scan for iBeacons
    final regions = <Region>[];
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      regions.add(Region(
          identifier: 'MyBeacon',
          proximityUUID: 'a86be991-76c7-4fc4-892a-551acf07c77c',
          major: null,
          minor: null));
    } else {
      regions.add(Region(identifier: 'com.beacon'));
    }
    flutterBeacon.monitoring(regions).listen((MonitoringResult result) {
      // result contains a region, event type and event state
    });
    // Start ranging for beacons
    _streamRanging =
        flutterBeacon.ranging(regions).listen((RangingResult result) {
      if (result != null && result.beacons.isNotEmpty) {
        // Get a list of beacons in range
        List<Beacon> beacons = result.beacons;

        // Iterate through beacons and get their data
        for (var beacon in beacons) {
          String uuid = beacon.proximityUUID;
          int major = beacon.major;
          int minor = beacon.minor;
          int rssi = beacon.rssi;
          // Do something with beacon data
          print(
              'Beacon detected: UUID=$uuid, major=$major, minor=$minor, rssi=$rssi');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // Stop ranging for beacons
    _streamRanging?.cancel();
    flutterBeacon.close;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'iBeacon Detection',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('iBeacon Detection'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Searching for iBeacons...'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but the issue when i run the code it show me this
[image]

while using this emulator
[image]
so I changed the emulator to
[image]
and now it shows me this error
[image]
[image]

it keeps showing me the same message until I stop the application
I have add the permission to AndroidManifest.xml file
How i can solve this and detect my beacons? I am fully new to this so I got stuck and cannot proceed further. I am using VS and an emulator from android studio

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. You cannot detect beacons or do any other bluetooth operations using an Android emulator.  Even though the workstation you are using likely supports Bluetooth LE, Android emulators to not bridge the bluetooth hardware on the workstation to the emulated Android device. The emulator acts like a phone without Bluetooth LE.
2. Just because a log line shows up in LogCat doesn't mean it is an error. Lots of messages are benign and do not indicate a problem.  This is true in your first log excerpt.
3. For your second log excerpt, the Security Exception does indicate a problem -- if you run on Android 12+ your code must get BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission from the user to be able to scan for beacons.

**Bottom line: you really need to get a physical Android phone for testing beacons** with your app and not rely on the emulator.  The underlying Android Beacon Library that flutter beacon uses under the hood does allow you to simulate beacons for emulator development as described [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon_simulator.html). However, that is for direct use of the native library, and I do not believe flutter beacon provides any flutter bindings to this beacon simulator, so you can only use it if you are writing native code.

Comment: oh thanks, I will try my code on a physical device. and one more thing i know is that i can't test this on iPhone i need to run the app on mac so will the code differ from mac to windows?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no iPhone simulator for Windows, all of the iOS dev tools only run on a MacOS workstation. While Flutter is a cross-platform framework, it does not eliminate the need to have a MacOS machine to build and test on iOS.   In theory you could make a dual-boot partition on Windows and make your Windows machine a Hackintosh so you can build and test on iOS.  But using the iOS simulator still doesn't let you detect beacons.  To test iOS you would need a MacOS/Hackintosh workstation and an iPhone.

Comment: ok thanks!! can you check the update I have posted below about detecting the beacons.